# installing openfire on centos7

Tags: centos

I have successful installed openfire on centos7 with maria-db as database, and created a user to test chat username=mickey, password=mickey. Centos machine on which openfire is installed with IP (192.168.1.141).

Now i have installed spark messenger on my windows laptop to test chat, but somehow i am unable to login.

As on windows i am successfully accessing admin console(192.168.1.141:9090). But spark login is not working. Spark is giving error "unable to verify certificate"

[image]

[image]

Comment: error during login "unable to verify certificate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was accessing openfire server that is installed in centos7 pc, on my windows pc(in which i have installed spark web app), spark was not connecting to centos server. I have to open these ports for public on centos, this helped me

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9090/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9094/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5222/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7777/tcp --permanent
```